# Is it readable or non-effective in C# to declare conditions before using IF

Tags: c#, if-statement

When writting codes, using if by following way

```
int something = 5;
bool possible = false;
if( something>0 && !possible){
   doSomething();
}
```

and

```
int something = 5;
bool possible = false;
bool condition1 = something > 0;
bool condition2 = !possible;
if( condition1 && condition2){
       doSomething();
}
```

Which is more readable?
Which is more effective?

I assume 2nd is better when case like

```
if( Something > (SomeOtherThing + SomeSomeThing) && !Something.Something.Possible)
```

I know this doesn't directly concern with c# but want to know especially in c#!

Comment: 1st is better. Less write ever. And use carriage return to have readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is non-effective.

When condition1 is false, it is not required to calculate condition2 in your example. Sometimes this calculation eats resources (request to DB for example). In this case 2nd option is non-effective.
However it is readable, particularly when you name condition variables in more convenient way, for example:

```
bool somethingIsPositive = somithing > 0;
bool itIsImpossible = !possible;
if(somethingIsPositive && itIsImpossible)
    ...
```

Also you can leverage Lazy class (if you use C#) to not claculate condition2 all the time (even when condition1 is false), so this is really more readable and hasn't performance problems (when condition2 takes time to calculate, not in your case :) ):

```
int something = GetNumber();
bool possible = GetPossibility();
var somethingIsPositive = new Lazy<bool>(() => something > 0);
var itIsImpossible = new Lazy<bool>(() => !possible);
if( somethingIsPositive.Value && itIsImpossible.Value){
       doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Effectiveness and efficiency are different things. Having that said, using patterns like lazy evaluation just for the sake of it looks like premature optimization at the cost of readability to me. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard and fast rule, but quite often the code can be much more readable if you extract to speaking variable names or method calls. In the following example the condition is absolutely clear.

```
bool UserIsAdmin() { ... }
bool UserOwnsItem() { ... }
bool UserMayAccessItem {
    return UserIsAdmin() || UserOwnsItem();
}

// ..

if (UserMayAccessItem()) {
    // do something here
}
```

On the other hand there certainly may be simple cases where adding variables does not increase readability.

It basically is a matter of style and preference. Just keep in mind that the code should be easily readable and speak for itself.

Comment: You will have performance problems because your code always evaluates all the conditions. Use Lazy<T>, see my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderVasilyev This depends on the actual underlying operations. Using patterns like lazy evaluation can decrease readability and I'd consider this only if I detect actual performance issues. Everything else would be premature optimization at the cost of simplicity and readability.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is preferable, not only because of shortcut evaluation, but also for maintainability.

I guarantee you that you or someone else will eventually change the conditions, without bothering to adapt the variable names, too, for example.